# Weblogic websocket: Cannot load platform configurator

Tags: java, websocket, weblogic

I'm trying to initialize a websocket endpoint based on this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket003.htm
using following code:

```
ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(EchoEndpoint.class, "/echo").build();
```

But I'm getting the exception below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load platform configurator
    at javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Configurator.fetchContainerDefaultConfigurator(ServerEndpointConfig.java:123)
    at javax.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfig.<init>(DefaultServerEndpointConfig.java:85)
    at javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Builder.build(ServerEndpointConfig.java:301)
```

I have no idea what should i do to avoid this. I see that I can provide some Configurator to the builder of the ServerEndpointConfig, but I have no idea what should be the parameters.

The server is Weblogic 12.1.1. should I use 12.1.2?

Comment: What is the question missing? I don't understand the -1

Comment: This tutorial might help. I don't think the Weblogic version should matter: http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/websocket-tomcat-8-ServerEndpointConfig-Configurator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to use Weblogic 12.1.2, because it's the first one, where websockets are implemented.

If you will be deploying to Weblogic only, you should probably use `weblogic.websocket.annotation.WebSocket` instead of `ServiceEndpoint` or programmatically as in your question. 
Following this tutorial you will be able to implement the endpoint:

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm

Just include the `wls-api.jar`, which you find under weblogic's `server/lib` directory.